# Jenkins - maven concurrent build - POM_* variables mixed

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

We have a maven job on jenkins that can build several projects. We have checked the "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" but we have realized that if we execute several builds in parallel, the variables POM_ARTIFACTID, POM_GROUPID and POM_VERSION are mixed during the execution (we use them to call another job that deploys the product)

Build_1 : POM_ARTIFACTID = AppA

Build_2 : POM_ARTIFACTID = AppB

Once Build_1 ends, it calls Deploy job but with POM_ARTIFACTID = AppB

Is there any explanation? I understand that Jenkins isolates completely every single execution and shouldn't have any impact